# Show data from database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to get my data from database to display on my view. Currently on my database table there are these columns: ID, ReportDescription, DateReported, CustomerId and MovieId.

What I need to do is use the CustomerId and MovieId to get to the name of the Customer and the name of the Movie.

This is my Model:

```
public class Malfunction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string ReportDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateReported { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public TablesController()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    // GET: Tables
    public ActionResult MalfunctionsList(MalfunctionDTO malfunctionDTO)
    {
        var malfunctions = _context.Malfunctions.ToList();

        return View(malfunctions);
    }
}
```

And this is the DTO:

```
public class MalfunctionDTO
{ 
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public List<int> MovieIds { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public Movie Movie { get; set; }

    public string ReportDescription { get; set; }

}
```

IdentityModel:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rent> Rents { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Malfunction> Malfunctions { get; set; }
```

Am i supposed to add properties like CustomerId and MovieId in my model in order for it to work?
Worth noting that i am very new to MVC and EF, so forgive me if I am a bit confused.

Comment: Is there a mapping you have configured between your DTO and the ViewModel?

Comment: @Thennarasan I have this in my MappingProfile Mapper.CreateMap<Malfunction, MalfunctionDTO>();..Code works the same way even if I remove this map. Also worth noting I am not using a viewModel for this, should I?

Comment: change this `var malfunctions = _context.Malfunctions.ToList();` to `var malfunctions = Mapper.Map<List<Malfunction>>(_context.Malfunctions.ToList());`
 ` Hope in your view you are calling `Malfunction` model

Comment: If you are using different names in model and Dto, then you need to map those in your AutoMapper CreateMap section.

Comment: @Thennarasan AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Comment: Do have this also in the configuration `Mapper.CreateMap<MalfunctionDTO, Malfunction>();`

Comment: @DSR this is in my AutoMapper MappingProfile: Mapper.CreateMap<Malfunction, MalfunctionDTO>();

Comment: @Thennarasan No I didn't. But even after adding it the error still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to change your mapping to look like below.

// For Id

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Malfunction, MalfunctionDTO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId, 
                     opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id));
```

**Update**

I assume you are not using Entity Framework Core.

Update your context like below. `vrtual` key word added.

```
public virtual DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

Also change

```
public class Malfunction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string ReportDescription { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateReported { get; set; }
}
```

Then you may need to add configuration in your `OnModelCreating`method something like this.Try without this first, if not work then add below configurations.

modelBuilder.Entity()
                .WithRequired(m => m.Movie);

modelBuilder.Entity()
                .WithRequired(m => m.Customer);

Comment: The customer value is still null and doesn't display on the view.

Comment: Okay, what you get back from database? I mean before map in to Dto?

Comment: Even if i dont have map in my MappingProfile, I get malfunction.Id, malfunction.ReportDescription and malfunction.DateReported. What i dont get are malfunction.Customer and malfunction.Movie because they appear to be null by the time they arrive on the view

Comment: You need to have lazy loading enabled in order to get related entities. What version of EntityFramework you use? It is worth providing your ApplicationDbContext class and movie class in your question.

Comment: Added ApplicationDbContext in post, EF Version 6.0.0.0

Comment: I have updated answer, your issue is bit complicated as you are not providing all the information.

Comment: What other info should I provide?

Comment: Fixed! Your solution worked. Also adding var customers = _context.Customers.ToList(); and var movies = _context.Movies.ToList(); before returning the view in my action worked aswell. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I mean OnModelCreating method, anyway glad it is working now :)

Comment: 1 more thing, should i add something in my mappingprofile for the MovieIds too? Because when I'm using postman to get the customers list, the movieIds is always null but the customerId is displaying what is expected.

Comment: You can't get list of MovieIds, because relationship isn't one to many. It will be one movieId